# javascript html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

send a value from javascript to html form input
having a value in javascript,
need to send that to 
<'input type='hidden' id='imgscr'/>
when submitting the form the value also should submit..
(set value from javascript to html form input)

Comment: Please be clearer, and make it a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I think the answer is

```
document.getElementById('imgsrc').value = js_variable;
```

You might want to put this function in the forms onsubmit handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, this is as easy as:

```
<form onsubmit="$('#imgscr').val('some value')">
```

You can substitute whatever you want for the value.

It is also possible to use the form notation if you set a name on your input field:

```
<form onsubmit="this.imgsrc.value='some value'">
  <input type="hidden" name="imgsrc" id="imgsrc">
</form>
```